# Customizing rules for Address Standardizer using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, tiger, address-parsing

Following PostGIS documentation, I created a custom table for having different [pagc_rules](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/rulestab.html) (also *pagc_lex* and *pagc_gaz*) so I can standardize/normalize addresses with different formats than the US where "house number" goes *after* the street name(s).
E.g. instead of *"123 Main Street"*, it would be *"Main Street 123"*.

I've tried adding rules to cover as many cases as possible, but it never works, so I'm not sure if the parser is even matching against my custom table or not.
What I did confirm, tough, is that my custom Lex and Gaz tables do work; I tested them with US addresses and the standard rules, and got my own lexicon for streets/states in the results.

**This works**

```
SELECT *
FROM standardize_address('ar_lex', 'ar_gaz', 'pagc_rules', '123 Main Street');
```

**This doesn't**

```
SELECT *
FROM standardize_address('ar_lex', 'ar_gaz', 'ar_rules', 'Main Street 123');
```

So I'm not sure what I might be missing to make it work with my custom rules as well.

I'm looking for some guidance more than specific answers, since I couldn't find any resources on the web where someone customized rules for using the address standardizer with countries other than US/Canada.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?